# PGAdmin column changing from text to text_integer

Tags: sql, pgadmin

I'm pretty new to SQL in general and I'm trying to teach myself. I'm using PGAdmin to play around with some of our school's data.

When I'm creating a query in the graphical query builder, I choose a column, we'll call it primary language. Once I click run the primary language column becomes primary_language_integer. So it doesn't return English, it'll return 1. Is this something I can fix so that it returns the text rather than the integer? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Go to the definition tab and choose one of the character options.

Comment: So I found a constraint attached to this column that seems ready to pull the matching text. But I have no idea how to use it. It doesn't show up in the graphical interface. Any ideas?